# batch script to rename '.txt' files, by using 'date' found within file

Tags: javascript, node.js, batch-rename

I am starting with this logic:

```
const fs = require("fs")

// Read directory
fs.readdir("./", (err, files) => {

  for (const file of files) {

    if (/[A-Z]/g.test(file)) {

      fs.rename(file, 'newFile.txt', (err) => {
        console.log('Renaming', file, "to", "newFile.txt")
        if (err) throw err
      })
    }
  }
})
```

I essentially want to iterate through a directory that has a couple dozen `.txt` files within it. I want to search for a date found within each `.txt` file and USE THAT as the new name of the file.

For instance within each text file, this is found within it (a date in this format) 
**2015-12-21**

I would like to iterate through the directory of .txt files, search and find a date in this format (`XXXX-XX-XX`), then use it as the new name for the file.

---

I am thinking this could be the regex for finding the date:

```
([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))
```

Below is an example of text file content, it has multiple content like the below: You'll notice the date to the right there, there are multiple dates listed like that, but they are all the same; so I just need to grab it and use it as the updated file name.

```
PRIORITY GOAL                                                                IN_PROGRESS_SINCE SOURCE  TYPE
-------- ------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------- ------- --------------------
4        Has received blahblahblah on improving physical activity              2015-12-21 15:51  MEMBER  NULL

          BARRIER              SENSITIVE STATUS   NOTE
---- ---- -------------------- --------- -------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          Needs counseling on  No        Not Met
```

Comment: can you provide an example of file content?

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski Yes, just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex expressions to search for a date:

```
// dir is the directory containing the file
// Specify utf8 as encoding to get a string
let fileContents = fs.readFileSync(path.join(dir, /*fs.Dirent*/file.name), 'utf8')
let dateMatches = fileContents.match(/[12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/)
```

If there is a date, `dateMatches` will be an array with length greater than zero. The first element will contain the first date encountered in the file contents.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

// Change ./example to whatever you like
let dir = './example'

fs.readdir(dir, {
  encoding: 'utf8',
  withFileTypes: true
}, (err, files) => {
  if (err) {
    // Error happened when reading the directory
    console.error(err)
    return
  }
  for (const file of files) {
    if (!file.isFile()) {
      // Directory or block device?
      continue;
    }

    // Read file contents
    let fileContents = fs.readFileSync(path.join(dir, file.name), 'utf8')
    let dateMatches = fileContents.match(/[12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/)
    if (dateMatches) {
      // There is a date here
      fs.rename(path.join(dir, file.name), path.join(dir, dateMatches[0]), (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err)
          // Do your error handling stuff here...

          return
        } else {
          console.log('Renamed', file.name, 'to', dateMatches[0])
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Note that the file may contain invalid dates, such as 2018-02-30. If that's an issue for you, you can validate the date with [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) or use a library such as [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

You might want to check the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) for details.

---

For example, if `./example/file1.txt` would contain the following:

```
DATE
====
2019-01-01
1970-12-31
```

executing the program above would rename it to `./example/2019-01-01`.

Comment: I get 'TYPERROR files is not iteratable'

Comment: for (const file of files) {
                     ^

TypeError: files is not iterable
    at fs.readdir (E:\careplan_report\2018_1\withgoals\app.js:8:22)
    at FSReqWrap.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:140:20)

Comment: Great answer, Thanks!